# Unresolved external symbols when linking to CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu, cusolver

Here is my code:

```
// --- CUDA solver initialization
cusolverDnHandle_t solver_handle = NULL;
cusolverDnCreate(&solver_handle);

cusolverDnDgesvd_bufferSize(solver_handle, Nrows, Ncols, &work_size));

cusolverDnDgesvd(solver_handle, 'A', 'A', Nrows, Ncols, d_A, Nrows, d_S, d_U, Nrows, d_V, Ncols, work, work_size, NULL, devInfo));
```

I get the following errors when linking:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cusolverDnCreate referenced in function main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cusolverDnDgesvd_bufferSize referenced in function main   
error LNK2019:unresolved external symbol cusolverDnDgesvd referenced in function main
```

How can I solve this? I have to add CUDA Linker something??

My environment:

- CUDA 7.5
- Windows 64bit
- Visual Studio2013 community

Comment: CUDA works only on NVIDIA GPUs I guess, Do you have NVIDIA GPU? If yes, then check if you have CUDA Compiler installed!

Comment: @Kensuke Did you link your code against the cuSolver library in the link step of your build?

Comment: @kiner_shah I have a TTX950.Also I installed CUDA Compilier.

Comment: @njuffa I have to add cusolver.lib on [Additional Dependancies]??

Comment: @Kensuke While I use MSVC on Win64 with CUDA 7.5, I never use the IDE, so I don't know how to specify additional libraries for linking in the IDE.

Comment: @njuffa Thank you, I resolved by own.